# Categorize contacts automatically created from inbound emails

Tags: groups, civirules, tags, contact-types, inbound-email

Would it be possible to set Civi that contacts which were created from inbound emails will be of a certain type? Or added to a certain group? A tag will be added to it, to allow a rule to catch it an appropriately add the contact to the correct type and groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_emailProcessor

The contact id will be in $params.

Comment: In addition: Afaik there is no extension or out of the box feature in CiviCRM that can do that.